# Is it possible to create a graphic with Google Charts where each column has several categories?

Tags: php, arrays, json, charts, google-visualization

I'm thinking of implementing the API of Google Charts with PHP to do some statistics, currently there are some graphics but they are developed with CSS directly to give a nice appearance:

[image]

After finding Google Chart I was thinking about the possibility of designing the same graph using the API, the problem is that in each column of the graph it is divided into three sections which I must report in a grouped way in the graph.

In the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) I can not see a similar example, but I think the JSON would have a structure similar to this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
            ([
              ['Month', 'Boards', 'Chairs', 'Speakers'],
              ['January',  {'Morning':80, 'Night':1000, 'Sunday':10}, {'Morning':20, 'Night':500, 'Sunday':60}, {'Morning':40, 'Night':10, 'Sunday':12}],
              ['February', {'Morning':30, 'Night':300, 'Sunday':20}, {'Morning':22, 'Night':60, 'Sunday':61}, {'Morning':90, 'Night':33, 'Sunday':22}],
              ['March']   etc .....
            ]);
```

I must show the categories of "Morning", "Night" and "Sunday" in each column, all I need is to know the structure of the JSON and how it looks visually using the API, but I can not see the correct way to interpret it or at least I have not found a tutorial where I explain a similar case, does anyone have a tutorial or guide to develop a similar graphic?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the details of Morning, Night, & Sunday to display above the columns,
need to use a `'tooltip'` [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole).
the tooltip column takes a `'string'` data type.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Boards', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'Chairs', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, 'Speakers', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}],
    ['January', 1090, '80 in the Morning\n1,000 in the night\n10 Sundays', 580, '20 in the Morning\n5000 in the night\n60 Sundays', 62, '40 in the Morning\n10 in the night\n12 Sundays'],
    ['February', 350, '30 in the Morning\n300 in the night\n20 Sundays', 143, '22 in the Morning\n60 in the night\n61 Sundays', 145, '90 in the Morning\n33 in the night\n22 Sundays'],
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    colors: ['#ffa726', '#7e57c2', '#7cb342'],
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'both'
    }
  };

  // add selection to make tooltip visible when drawn
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart.setSelection([{row: 0, column: 1}]);
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```